# What could cause internet speed to drop on devices but others work fine?

Tags: networking

Ok,  I have suddenlink 50m internet.  My internet will drop down to about 15m.  We've had techs come look and on his device using our internet it shows it working at 50m, but on our 2 pcs and 2 ipads it only shows about 15m.  Why would that be?  My one pc is plugged directly into the suddenlink box while all the other devices connect to the box wireless.  I have full purchase of McAfee Total Protection and have done many scans and nothing.  0 issues found.  But the suddenlink guys phone and laptop will get 50m no problem running off our wireless internet box.  Any thoughts?

The pc its directly hooked into runs windows 8 and literally was just bought 1 month ago.  The ipads arrived 3 days ago.  The one pc is over 2 years old and has windows 7.  All devices have McAfee and show nothing when scanned.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed on the devices that show reduced speed?

Comment: Are you using 2ghz or 5ghz wifi and what channel is it set for. His equipment could all be on the 5ghz channel which is newer so it is less used.  In my experience Mcafee is near useless, try avira or malwarebytes.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those problems where you just have to be there to see it.

I worked at a ISP and this was one of the most common problems - To begin with:

Wireless - NEVER guaranteed, could be a new light, microwave or phone that interferes - most common problem is that you are working perfectly, but, a neighbour could then get a new router (or device listed before) which completely interferes with your setup.

Wired - This is always better than wireless, but, if you are still not seeing top speeds, it could be your antivirus and I would recommend doing one test with, one test without - if you can, try safe mode with networking.

If speeds continue to be low on wired, it could be that your ISP is simply contented, or the site you are visiting doesn't have enough bandwidth.

Perform your tests from speedtest.net and choose a server near you.

Comment: I am performing tests on speedtest.net.  I have tried running tests pre installing and post installing my McAfee.  Only a couple devices are wireless and the one is wired.  Thanks for the response

Comment: I went in on safe mode with networking and still running at 15m.  I just don't want them looking at me and saying its my devices and not them when the supervisor comes over with his equipment.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ethernet cable? Also, what is the actual specification of your machine... pretty much any machine should be able to get over 15, but, want to make sure!